# SendMail Error Message: 553 5.1.8 … Domain of sender address … does not exist

Tags: linux, email, dns, sendmail, postfix-mta

I setup sendmail server with inhmail.walkingtree.in in local

when i tried to sen dmail from other email servers i am getting the following error ,

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  mail1@inhmail.walkingtree.in
    SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<srinivasa.nallapati@walkingtree.in> SIZE=2548:
    host inhmail.walkingtree.in [122.175.35.121]:
    553 5.1.8 <srinivasa.nallapati@walkingtree.in>... Domain of sender address srinivasa.nallapati@walkingtree.in does not exist

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
```

I installed sendmail server in 192.168.1.145. the domain name of .145 is inhmail.walkingtree.in

i opened port 25 in firewall in system and router as well .

Mail receiving and sending in 192.168.1.0/24 is working fine with @inhmail.walkingtree.in.

Please help that **`how  sendmail  can receive mails from external email servers.`**

**UPADTED**

```
> [srinivas@localhost ~]$ echo "check_mail jd@walkingtree.in" | sendmail -d8.20 -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> check_mail         input: jd @ walkingtree . in
Basic_check_mail   input: jd @ walkingtree . in
tls_client         input: $| MAIL
D                  input: < > < ? > < ! "TLS_Clt" > < >
D                returns: < ? > < > < ? > < ! "TLS_Clt" > < >
A                  input: < > < ? > < ! "TLS_Clt" > < >
A                returns: < > < ? > < ! "TLS_Clt" > < >
TLS_connection     input: $| < > < ? > < ! "TLS_Clt" > < >
TLS_connection   returns: OK
tls_client       returns: OK
CanonAddr          input: < jd @ walkingtree . in >
canonify           input: < jd @ walkingtree . in >
Canonify2          input: jd < @ walkingtree . in >
dns_getcanonname(walkingtree.in, trymx=1)
dns_getcanonname: trying walkingtree.in. (AAAA)
    NO: errno=0, h_errno=4
dns_getcanonname: trying walkingtree.in. (A)
    NO: errno=0, h_errno=4
dns_getcanonname: trying walkingtree.in. (MX)
    NO: errno=0, h_errno=4
dns_getcanonname: trying walkingtree.in.localdomain (AAAA)
    NO: errno=0, h_errno=1
Canonify2        returns: jd < @ walkingtree . in >
canonify         returns: jd < @ walkingtree . in >
Parse0             input: jd < @ walkingtree . in >
Parse0           returns: jd < @ walkingtree . in >
CanonAddr        returns: jd < @ walkingtree . in >
SearchList         input: < + From > $| < F : jd @ walkingtree . in > < U : jd @ > < D : walkingtree . in > < >
F                  input: < jd @ walkingtree . in > < ? > < + From > < >
F                returns: < ? > < >
SearchList         input: < + From > $| < U : jd @ > < D : walkingtree . in > < >
U                  input: < jd @ > < ? > < + From > < >
U                returns: < ? > < >
SearchList         input: < + From > $| < D : walkingtree . in > < >
D                  input: < walkingtree . in > < ? > < + From > < >
D                  input: < in > < ? > < + From > < >
D                returns: < ? > < >
D                returns: < ? > < >
SearchList       returns: < ? >
SearchList       returns: < ? >
SearchList       returns: < ? >
Basic_check_mail returns: $# error $@ 5 . 1 . 8 $: "553 Domain of sender address " " does not exist"
check_mail       returns: $# error $@ 5 . 1 . 8 $: "553 Domain of sender address " " does not exist"
> [srinivas@localhost ~]$
```

**Working:**

Yes thanks ,now it is working .

problem is i am unable to ping walkingtree.in ,due to local DNS server settings.I removed dbs server in network connections  now i am able to get mails from GMail and walkingtree.in

when  i am using dns server , i am  able to  ping www.walkingtree.in  but not walkingtree.in . can you please help me to able to ping walkingtree.in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You sendmail thinks that envelope sender's domain walkingtree.in does not exist (no `MX`, `A`, `AAAA` DNS records). It refuses to accept messages with such envelope sender because there will be no way to send back (eventual) bounce messages (reports about email delivery problems).

You may use `nslookup` (or `dig`) to check if the server sees the DNS records:

`nslookup -type=mx walkingtree.in`
    `dig walkingtree.in MX`

---

**IF YOU USE SENDMAIL** (not postfix) then as root execute the command below to locate the problem:

```
echo "check_mail jd@walkingtree.in" | sendmail -d8.20 -bt
```

In case of "`Undefined ruleset check_mail`" error try:

```
echo "checkmail jd@walkingtree.in" | sendmail -d8.20 -bt
```

-d8.20 turns on tracking of DNS queries
checkmail - equivalent of check_mail used with FEATURE(delay_checks)

Comment: can you please check above update ,i placed the output of ur command

Comment: inhmail.walkingtree.in  is  not able to receive mails from Gmail

Comment: sorry , now i am able to get mails from @gmail.com but not walkingtree.in

Comment: It seems to be DNS related problem. (DNS resolver configutation + maybe local DNS servers).

Comment: thanks. Now it is working after some changes in local dns server